# Crontab and variables

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I tried to use variables in my Crontab, but faced with fact that they work strange. Here is an example:

```
FOO=echo date
BAR=/root/foobar
COMB=echo date >> /root/comb

* * * * * $FOO >> $BAR
* * * * * $COMB
```

**foobar** works fine, but **comb** doesn't (comb file wasn't created).
Also things like:

```
FOO=echo `date`
BAR=/root/foobar

* * * * * $FOO >> $BAR
```

or

```
FOO=echo date
BAR=~/foobar

* * * * * $FOO >> $BAR
```

don't work as well. Seems like there are some restrictions of symbols that could be used in variables in crontab file, am I right?

My goal is simple checking if a ruby script is already running and restart it if it's not:

```
STARTSCRIPT='ruby ~/RubyScripts/Script.rb'
*/5 * * * * pgrep -f "$STARTSCRIPT" &>/dev/null || $STARTSCRIPT
```

but it doesn't work due to those restriction. Or maybe I do something wrong)
All stuff works at lx branded zone **Ubuntu 14.04 LX** 0150320 inside SmartOS (some kind of Solaris).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no restriction of symbols, its just they have special meaning, that you are unaware of.

```
FOO='/bin/date'
BAR='/root/foobar'
COMB='echo /bin/date >> /root/comb'

* * * * * $FOO >> $BAR
* * * * * $COMB
```

In second code snippet:

```
FOO='/bin/date'  #there is absolutely no point in echoing here
BAR='/root/foobar'

* * * * * $FOO >> $BAR
```

**Edit:**

This is how you can check for you the status script and run it when not running:

```
SCRIPT_NAME='/absolutepath/RubyScripts/Script.rb'
SCRIPT_CMD="/usr/bin/ruby $SCRIPT_NAME"

*/5 * * * * pgrep $SCRIPT_NAME > /dev/null || $SCRIPT_CMD
```

Comment: Thanks. So, my mistake was in assigning expressions, backticks must be used.
But third snippet works only in such form:
`STARTSCRIPT=ruby ~/RubyScripts/Script.rb
*/5 * * * * pgrep -f "$STARTSCRIPT" >/dev/null || $STARTSCRIPT`
Could you please also explain why I'm not able to use `&>` in crontab expression?
Thanks a lot.